# Is there any way to perform recommendation for entities with one to many association?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, mahout-recommender

I'm trying out recommendation system(academic exercise) for a specific use case where users and items are one to many associated. Say at a given time a particular item can be owned by only one user. User can own multiple items at a time. Any particular item has many similar items which might interest the owning user. I want to find an item and recommend it to user. Usually in user based recommendation, entities will be of many to many association. If user U1 owns items I1,I2,I3 and user U2 owns  items I1,I2,I3,I4 we would recommend  I4 to U1. In my case one item can be owned by only one user at a given time. How to perform recommendation in this case. Is it possible to perform user based recommendation?

Comment: Can users 'trade' items? is there an extensive history of owning different items, that are sometimes available (owned by nobody)? Without this I don't know that any recommendation system is useful.

Comment: Hi Sean, The same item can be owned by different user at different point of times. But generally it will not happen very frequently.

Comment: In what sense are items similar then, if it's not defined in terms of user behavior... you'd have to say more about what you believe is the basis of such a process. Do you have categories on the items? etc.

Comment: They have categories. Its something like tags on the data. Each item can have multiple tags associated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is always to conert one problem to another. Given one-to-many information, you can for each item X (knowing some kind of similarity measure, which is **required** here, without it you cannot do any recomendation) you create an object "items similar to X to some extent" call it C[X], and once you go through all items -- you get new kind of data. You have users, and "items clusters" C. Now you can assume that user A "likes" cluster C[X] iff user A likes any item from C[X]. This way you have many-to-many relation on the same data, with a bit of "smoothing". Now you can use any kind of existing system, and once you get the recommendation C[Y] you "recommend" any free (avaliable) item from C[Y].

Comment: A similarity metric isn't strictly required for recommendation, although it's a common way to proceed. But yeah that's the whole question here, what is the basis of any computation here? describing how a neighborhood-based algorithm works from there doesn't really help.

Comment: It is required in **this** context, because without such measure, you have no knowledge about recommendation (as all items that you know something about are already taken).

Comment: What's required is some knowledge of the items, yes, but you certainly don't need a similarity metric in general. For example latent factor models are not based on any explicit similarity metric.

Comment: I see your point. Yet still - I was refering only to **this** situation, and only to "some kind of similarity measure", as the concept of similarity, not any metric in the strict sense.